# Problems by understanding the Tycho working flow

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

So im trying to understand the the building of Eclipse Plugins with Eclipse Tycho.
My parent pom is this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>eclipse.plugin.mavenresults.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>maventests-for-junitview</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>maventests-for-junitview Maven Plugin</name>

<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0</maven>
</prerequisites>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <tycho-version>1.0.0</tycho-version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>oxygen</id>
    <url> http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7 </url>
    <releases>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
 </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <goalPrefix>maventests-for-junitview</goalPrefix>
                <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>help-goal</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>run-its</id>
        <build>

            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <debug>true</debug>
                        <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it</cloneProjectsTo>
                        <pomIncludes>
                            <pomInclude>*/pom.xml</pomInclude>
                        </pomIncludes>
                        <postBuildHookScript>verify</postBuildHookScript>
                        <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo</localRepositoryPath>
                        <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>integration-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install</goal>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<modules>
    <module>../bundles/maventests-for-junitview</module>
</modules>
```

and the pom of the Plugin

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>maventests-for-junitview</artifactId>
    <groupId>eclipse.plugin.mavenresults.parent</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../maventests-for-junitview/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>maventests-for-junitview.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>maventests-for-junitview</artifactId>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0.I20090604-2000</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0.v20140318-2214</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.debug</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.debug.ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0.v20090603</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.mylyn.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench</artifactId>
            <version>3.24.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

and the following Error is the result. Can someone help me?

> [ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.MavenExecutionException: Could not setup plugin ClassRealm: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.debug:org.eclipse.debug.ui:3.5.0.v2009060

I think, my poms are bad written. The Tutorials of the Web aren't exlpaning very well.